# configuration using node config module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the [config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) module in node js.
Under config/default.yaml, I have following configuration

```
Facebook:
    appKey: ""
    appSecret: ""

Twitter:
    consumerKey: ""
    consumerSecret: ""
```

When I use require('config'), the returned object only contains Facebook. No Twitter. Any idea? I am totally cluless

Comment: Check for stray whitespace characters before `Twitter:`

Comment: @Plynx There is no whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I landed here. https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/27

Seems like if we use yaml, then we should declare js-yaml in our dependency list and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this

```
var Facebook = require('config').Facebook;
var Twitter = require('config').Twitter;
```

Does this give any errors ?

Comment: var Twitter = require('config').Twitter; Gives error. It says that Twitter is undefined

Comment: I have the same issue, I wonder if there is any resolution on this?